# ExtJS 6 Charts -- change title color

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs6

I have a chart with a title like so:

```
{
  xtype:"cartesian",
  axes:[{
    type:"numeric",
    position:"bottom",
    fields:"ABC",
    title:"BLAH",
    ....
    ...
   }]
}
```

previously in with ext 4 I was using css to style the tspan el

```
tspan{
  fill:"#fff";
}
```

but in ext6 the same doesnt work nor can I inspect the tspan element like I was able to in ext 4.

I also tried:

```
title:"<font color='#fff'><BLAH></font>"
```

this did not work and in place of the title it shows the above font tag

how can I change my chart title to white?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If given a String, the 'text' attribute of the title sprite will be set, otherwise the style will be set.

use the config style to set the text color, just add

```
style: {
color: #fff
}
```

you can read more here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Axis
same on ext 6

Comment: thanks! this worked for me: title:{color:"#fff", text:"BLAH"},